# App_Code in local IIS and Azure/TFS build

Tags: asp.net, azure, tfs, app-code

I am using Visual Studio Express 2013 for Web & developing web APPS ( not sites ) on .net 4.5.

I build,test & view my site on a local IIS 7.5.
I host on Azure - using App Services.
I build and release to an App Services slot using VSTS Online

I have my classes in an App_Code folder - files are marked as compile
This appears to be the only way I can set this up to work on local IIS ( or am I missing something ?)
And it all works - all classes are available

But I need to build and release on VSTS/TFS ( using VS Team explorer to push)
I am using the standard Azure Web App build definition module on TFS - 
Which takes the App_Code folder and moves it into the bin folder - but does not compile it - thus breaking the classes when they are deployed

I have tried renaming App_Code but that breaks local and still does not compile on TFS

What am I missing - how do I get TFS to either compile my classes OR copy the App_Code folder to the root ( not ideal but hey it works )?

Comment: How did you manager your APP_Code folder in local? Did you want to use the complied classes during the web app  deploy? Are you building  the whole net solution or just  .csproj project?

Comment: I create an App_Code folder in VS using Add ASP.NET folder - then create my files in there. Then I build. I am building just the project ( actually solution in this case is just one project). But when I Commit & Push to VSTS it moves the App_Code folder into /bin. But this does not compile - so the classes are not avaible to me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In TFS, dll files will be generated under `bin` folder when you build a Class Library project. This is the correct phenomenon. Suggest you to **create a Nuget  Packages** to manage your class libraries . And you can add a "NuGet Installer" task at the top of your build definition to restore the nuget packages for your solution.

[image]

If you are using vNext Build on TFS. There also has been a very detail tutorial [Build and Deploy Azure Web Apps using Team Foundation Server/Services vNext Builds](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/tfssetup/2016/04/01/build-and-deploy-azure-web-apps-using-team-foundation-serverservices-vnext-builds/) for you reference.

Comment: I am using exactly that build - exact same steps. My problem is that no matter where I place  a  .cs  file it just does not get compiled. So if I create an AppCode folder and place my .cs classes there or even if I place them in the root - they do not get picked up in the build - or at least the site breaks with 'xxx not declared' so I am assuming they are not being included in dll

Comment: I have also tried to include a seperate ClassLibrary project in the solution & reference that - and once again it works on local IIS - but not on Azure after build - In the old days if I set up a website project (not a webapp) and included a ClassLibrary project & referenced it, it moved a copy of the ClassLibrary.dll into the projects bin folder - this does not happen with a WebApp